# No templates found matching: 'HttpTrigger'

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-functions

I have installed [Azure Functions Core Tools V.3.x](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local?tabs=windows%2Ccsharp%2Cportal%2Cbash%2Ckeda#v2) from Microsoft.

I am trying to follow a learning path. So far it worked fine when working with nodes. Anyway, now I am trying to experiment with .net, so what I did is the following:

```
func init
```

Select `dotnet`, and it generates files in my workspace fine.
Next.

```
func new
```

And chose `HttpTrigger`, then I got this error:

> ```
> No templates found matching: 'HttpTrigger'.
> To list installed templates, run 'dotnet new --list'.
> To search for the templates on NuGet.org, run 'dotnet new HttpTrigger --search'.
> ```

So by researching and reading, I tried to follow a suggestion and ended up with this command to install the templates:

```
dotnet new -i Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ItemTemplates
```

And indeed it has confirmed that I have `HttpTrigger` installed as you can see in the image below. But still has the same issue as mentioned before "No templates found matching: 'HttpTrigger'."

My question is, what is the possibility of going wrong within the command line where the template is not found?

> Note:
>
> - I have used cmd and PowerShell with administrator privileges as well.
> - When I try to create a project in Visual Studio 2019 it can create HttpTriggers without issues.
> - I have both Visual Studio 2019 and 2022 installed on Windows 10 environment.
> - This is the first time I have used Azure Functions Core Tools and learned it.

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Note: This solution applies for all other functions features that get the same issue with `No templates found matching: etc...`.

For those that face a similar issue with `HttpTrigger` or other Azure function features. Here is the cause and the solution to the issue and how I solved it:

##### Cause of the problem

having different SDK versions install created the issue.

##### How to validate

So running this command

`dotnet --list-sdks`

This will show that the installed `dotnet` version, in my case both `dotnet 5` and `dotnet 6 preview` were installed.

#### Solution

so what I did, what I used

`dotnet new globaljson`

in my project/working folder and then updated the version in `global.json` to 5, and it worked .

Comment: Did not work for me

Comment: @CuriousBenjamin I am not sure which error you get, but maybe it is another problem you have even thus you might see similar error as mine.

Comment: I can confirm this solution did work for me. I first checked what my latest installed v5 sdk version was, then created new globaljson, then swapped the version from v6 to the latest installed v5.

Comment: This also resolved "no templates found matching" when issuing `dotnet new webapi` +  extra arguments in an environment with side-by-side installs of VS2019 and VS2022 (and thus dotnet SDK v5 & v7 together).

Answer (score 6):

- We have researched in our local environment while it is working fine when i am creating the http trigger function using azure function core tools v3 & dotnet sdk version 5 family.
- If you are using dotnet sdk version "**6.0.100-preview.7.21379.14**" which is in preview creation of functions through function core tools
  will fail.
- If creation of function with .net sdk version 5 & function core tool v3 you can refer below solution shared in the [below blog](https://adamstorr.azurewebsites.net/blog/azure-functions-cli-failing-after-preview-install)

Comment: Still getting this error with dotnet sdk version 6.0.202 which is out of preview

Answer (score 1):

[Microsoft documentation alerts that you shouldn't use two different package managers to install Azure Functions Core Tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local?tabs=v4%2Cwindows%2Ccsharp%2Cportal%2Cbash#changing-core-tools-versions). Either this is the issue (it was mine at least), or you have made Azure Functions Core Tools confused somehow or have several versions.
In my case:
I checked for global packages installed with npm:

```
npm list -g --depth 0
```

Confirmed that I had a Azure Functions Core Tools outdated global package v3.

Removed it with:

```
npm uninstall -g azure-functions-core-tools
```

Reinstalled it using the MSI installer you can find [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local?tabs=v4%2Cwindows%2Ccsharp%2Cportal%2Cbash#install-the-azure-functions-core-tools)

All good after this. Because its the Core Tools v4, I can now use .Net6 with it, all templates included.

Comment: after your fix I put it in a devcontainer, i guess that helps too. But you solution has fixed my problem