# Azure Timer trigger is not working in .net 5 isolated function app

Tags: azure, timer, azure-functions

Azure Timer trigger is not working in .net 5 isolated function app with the CRON expression to get triggered for every minute.
This is working fine if we run that in local visual studio.

public static class NotificationScheduler
{

[Function("NotificationScheduler")]

```
    public static void Run([TimerTrigger("1-2 * * * * *")] MyInfo myTimer, FunctionContext context)
    {

        var logger = context.GetLogger("NotificationScheduler");
        logger.LogInformation($"Notification Scheduler trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
        //logger.LogInformation($"Next timer schedule at: {myTimer.ScheduleStatus.Next}");

       
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Is it not running at all or is there some error message? Did you check in Application insights if the app is getting triggered? It is possible that it is triggering but failing. Can you attach your code so we can attempt to recreate the issue?

Comment: i have added my code. i am using .net isolated function app and i checked the application insights and nothing gets logged there as a trigger.

Answer (score -1):

As per your ask I have run the function in my local environment and it is working fine for me below is my code for reference make changes accordingly on your environment.

1. Created Function App in Azure Portal

[image]
2. Below is the Code which I have Used in function App

[image]

Function1.cs

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;


namespace KrishFuncTimerTriggerApp
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static void Run([TimerTrigger("0 * * * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer, TraceWriter log)
        {
           log.Info($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
        }

      
}
```

3. Then I went to `Code+Integration` and when I did a Test Run my function app ran every minute as per my logic

[image]

4. As per the below Image `.Net` isolated function is not supported for editing in Azure Portal.

[image]

Also, try to check your SDK version as per this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68816359/15969833) and [blog](https://adamstorr.azurewebsites.net/blog/azure-functions-cli-failing-after-preview-install) if you are using SDK version "**6.0.100-preview.7.21379.14**"  as it is in Preview could be the reason why your function app is not working, if that is the case then try to downgrade your function app.

Also Check the [Cron expression link](https://www.easycron.com/faq/What-cron-expression-does-easycron-support) for  further details

Comment: i have added my code. i am using .net isolated function app and it is not supporting the code+test from the azure portal.

Comment: 1. You can create Function App through Azure Portal only for the Version 3.1 and 6 as per this [Image](https://i.imgur.com/OgcYnxW.png).
2. You can create Isolated Functions through VS or core tools locally and deploy it to Azure Portal.
3. If you create function app locally and deploy it to Azure portal you cannot make changes in Code+Test you need to make changes in locally and redeploy as per this [image](https://i.imgur.com/Tl6Q3So.png).

Comment: As per this [Image](https://i.imgur.com/KhKfIrp.png) '.net' Isolated function is not supported for editing in Azure portal. when I try to do my application is automatically downgraded to 3.1

Comment: I am not intended to write the code in portal. I am writing the code in visual studio and deploying into azure.

Comment: I have written my code in visual studio then also it is not getting triggered when we deploy into azure

Comment: Could you please help me with the Corn Expression that you are trying to use. Also help us with the expected behavior?

Comment: ([TimerTrigger("1-2 * * * * *")] this should fire 2 times at starting of the minute.. here 1-2 denotes range of seconds

Comment: Have you installed this [packages](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions) and gone through this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide?tabs=browser&pivots=development-environment-vs#execution-context)

Comment: yes i have followed everything mentioned in that documents and the function app timer trigger is working if we run locally

Comment: @Aditya did you ever get a resolution here? My timer function isn't working although the functions app is running fine. I've checked my timer trigger as well; it worked before I moved it to an isolated structure.